# F# Fold while building a list using cons (::) as opposed to concat (@)

Tags: list, f#, concatenation, fold

I have the following function which does what I want. But is uses the concat (@) operator which is O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the (::) operator

```
let myFunc s m cs =  
    let n = s * m
    let c = [n - s] // single element list
    (n,  cs @ c) // concat the new value to the accumulated list

let chgLstAndLast = 
    [0.99; 0.98; 1.02] 
    |> List.fold (fun (s, cs) m -> myFunc s m cs) (1., [])
```

The chgLstAndLast returns the last value and list of the results generated:

```
val chgLstAndLast : float * float list = (0.989604, [-0.01; -0.0198; 0.019404])
```

I would like to improve the above in three ways.

1. Use con (::) rather than concat (@)
2. Move the list accumulation from the myFunc to the List.fold operation
3. Make sure that the resulting list order remains the same as above (i.e last result is at end of list as opposed to the head)

For example, I would like to write a `myFunc` like this

```
let myFunc s m cs =  
    let n = s * m
    let c = n - s // single element, but not as list
    (n, c) // No concat here
```

But when I do, I don't see how to use (::) cons in the Fold function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, what you want to do is a `fold` while keeping all intermediary results. This is almost what `List.scan` does; it also returns the initial state.

```ml
let chgLstAndLast data =
    let inner s m =
        let n = s * m
        n, n - s
    let processedData = data |> List.scan (fun (s, _) n -> inner s n) (1.0, 1.0)
    let lastResult = processedData |> List.reduce (fun _ n -> n)
    let seq = processedData |> List.tail |> List.map snd
    lastResult, seq
```

To explain a bit more on this code: first I declare an inner function to make the code cleaner to the exterior world (assuming `myFunc` isn't needed by other code), then I use `scan` to get all intermediary results from a `fold`, which is a built-in way to do your fold + accumulator trick.
The last value is obtained with a `reduce` trick since there's no built-in "last of list" function, and the intermediary results are the second parts of the processed data, except for the first element which is the initial state.

Comment: List.scan seems to be exactly what I want. Thank you. The Inner function does need to be broken out but that is fairly easy. One question is about lastResult. Why not just let lastResult = fst processedData.[processedData.Length-1] instead of a List.reduce. Is there an advantage to using reduce?

Comment: Since F#'s List is a linked list, length is O(n) and indexing is O(n) too, so list[list.Length - 1] has to go through the list twice. Reduce only traverses it once. If you want to make it cleaner, write a recursive `List.last` function (it's super-easy).

Comment: Now I see. Thank you! Your explanation regarding `Reduce` vs my version was very helpful.